# Best way to get reference to local (SiteCollection) Term Store Group

Tags: term-store, managed-metadata, taxonomy

I'm trying to hook up some Site Columns (TaxonomyFields) to Term Sets in the the local (SiteCollection) term store.  In some cases I may need to actually create the term sets and this code will be running as a FeatureReceiver on the Feature that is provisioning the SiteColumns (in CAML).  So, I'm able to do this:

```
var session = new TaxonomySession(site);
var termStore = session.DefaultSiteCollectionTermStore;
```

But now how do I get the proper taxonomy group (the one private to my site collection) from the termStore.Groups collection?  Do I really have to just loop through it looking for "Site Collection - SCHostname-path-to-site" and hope that funky url translation works out and that there are no odd access mappings at play?  That seems very sloppy and I have to believe I'm approaching this wrong.  Is there a way to find out the current site's "group association" so I can just call termStore.GetGroup(id)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a new method in the 2010 SP1 API: Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TermStore.GetSiteCollectionGroup(SPSite currentSite)

you can use like this source code:

```
session = new TaxonomySession(site);

                        //Retrieve all Term stores from site collection
                        termstores = session.TermStores;

                        foreach (TermStore termstore in termstores)
                        {                                      
                            foreach (TermSet termSet in termstore.GetSiteCollectionGroup(site).TermSets)
                            {
                                foreach (Term term in termSet.Terms)
                                {
                                    row[0] = site.Url.ToString();
                                    row[1] = site.RootWeb.ToString();
                                    row[2] = termstore.Name.ToString();
                                    row[3] = termstore.GetSiteCollectionGroup(site).Name.ToString();
                                    row[4] = termSet.Name.ToString();
                                    row[5] = term.Name.ToString();
                                    dt.Rows.Add(row);
                                }
                            }                                                                
                        }
```